# Suppress json quotes in views

Tags: json, playframework

I have a complex JSON I return it to view and in the view I am trying to just print some values but they are printed out with "".

```
#{list items:hotels.results, as:'hotel'}

    ${hotel.name}

#{/list}
```

so for instance hotel name will be `"Golder Hotel"` (but it should be `Golder Hotel`).

Is there any way to escape quotes (instead of doing `replace("\"","")`)?

Comment: Shouldn't that read *"Suppress JSON quotes"*? (I fail to see how commas are related, and *escaping* generally refers to some way to actually print things?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `replace("\"","")`, because if your string is `I said, "Good night"`, it will be `I said, Good night`, and you lose your full message.

Actually, in your example, `hotel` is JSONObject, and `hotel.name` is JSONString (not String). When you write `${hotel.name}`, Play! implicit that `${hotel.name.toString()}`, and JSONString will be add quote.

So, to solve this problem, you need to write `${hotel.getAsString("name")}`

I think it's helpful.